# If statement troubles in 7 hours JAVA Leap Year

Tags: java, date, if-statement, monthcalendar

I am 4 weeks into Java class with 0 experience.
I'm asked to create a program which asks use to input the numerical representation of a month example 1 would be january & also an input for the year and have the program output **display the month** **how many days in the month** and **if it is a leap year**. This is one of my many attempts shortened. What am I doing wrong it starts with january n matter the input.

```
package leapmonth;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LeapMonth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int Year;
        int MonthNumber;

    String MonthString;    


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " HELLO, WELCOME TO LEAPMONTH ");
    MonthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( " Please enter the numerical respresentation of the month");
    MonthNumber = Integer.parseInt(MonthString);
    MonthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( " Please enter the year");
    Year = Integer.parseInt(MonthString);

    if( MonthNumber == 1 && Year % 4 == 0 && Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 == 0)
    {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The month is January. " + "January has 31 days in it" + " and is also a leap year "); 
    }   
    else if( MonthNumber == 1 && Year % 4 != 0 && Year % 100 == 0 || Year % 400 != 0)
    {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The month is January. " + "January has 31 days in it" + " and it is not a leap year ");   
    }
    else if( MonthNumber == 2 && Year % 4 == 0 && Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 ==0)
    {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The month is February. " + "February has 29 days in it because this is a leap year ");  
    } 
    else if( MonthNumber == 2 && Year % 4 != 0 && Year % 100 == 0 || Year % 400 != 0)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The month is February. " + "February has 28 days in it because this is not a leap year ");
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not mean you think it means:

```
MonthNumber == 1 && Year % 4 == 0 && Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 == 0
```

I think what you want is this:

```
MonthNumber == 1 && Year % 4 == 0 && (Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 == 0)
```

with emphasis on the parentheses.

Explanation: both the `||` and the `&&` operators have the same precedence and, therefore, they associate left-to-right.

Without parentheses, your logic is flawed in the sense that any year which is a multiple of 400 will yield `true`.

For instance, imagine that `Year=2000` and `MonthNumber=25`

Then

```
MonthNumber == 1 && Year % 4 == 0 && Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 == 0
```

evaluates to

```
false && true && false || true
```

step by step this then evaluates to

```
((false && true) && false) || true
(false && false) || true
false || true
true
```

In that example, as long as the last condition yields `true` then the entire expression will also yield `true`. I presume this is not what you want.

Note: I did not accurately spend the time to verify the entirely of your logic. I merely found this one simple bug, but there might be others.

Comment: sir or madaam, I have been close to tears trying to figure this out. Im in my 30's with 18 year old students and this is all new. Thank you so much THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Comment: Right result but wrong reasoning. Java `&&` has higher precedence than `||`; see the grammar rules in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html . In fact all HLLs I know have 'and' above 'or' except those that have no precedence at all (e.g. APL, Forth, LISP) probably because it's a mathematical convention as @paulo references. In this case the right operand of the `||` has no (further) `&&` so the result is the same. Also (like C/C++ etc) `&&` `||` but not `&` `|` etc are "short-circuit"; their operands aren't evaluated *at all* if not needed to determine the result. ...

Comment: ... In this case of simple computations it doesn't matter, but the structurally similar `month==2 && countFilesAndEraseThem()>0` would only erase your files in February because in other months the result of the `&&` operator is known to be false because the left operand yields false regardless of what the right operand might yield.

Answer (score 2):

You have an awful lot of repetition in your code. Split it out, and make things a lot easier for you. Many of your variables (generically speaking, not just in the programming term) only change once. The Year only matters if the month is February.

```
String MonthString;
int Days;
bool IsLeapYear = Year % 4 == 0 && (Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 == 0);
String Leap = "";
if (!IsLeapYear) {
    Leap = "not ";
}

if (MonthNumber == 1) {
    MonthString = "January";
    Days = 31;
}
else if (MonthNumber == 2) {
    MonthString = "February";
    if (IsLeapYear) {
        Days = 29;
    }
    else {
        Days = 28;
    }
}
else if (MonthNumber == 3) {
    MonthString = "March";
    Days = 31;
}
// etc....

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The month is " + MonthString + ". " + 
    MonthString + " has " + Days + " days in it and it is " + Leap + 
    "a leap year.");
```

Comment: Due to all the snow my classes have been canceled weeks in a row. I'm getting assignments via email and I really have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: That's a shame. The best thing you can do, it to keep things simple. Let me know if you have questions  with what I was doing here.

Comment: I have many questions . Super beginner thinking in pseudo code at best. No idea. My program working good until I try to add a do while for if user enters an invalid input. Ieither get invalid input infinite loop or it says invalid upon first entry no matter what then works proper..... not really understanding things you guys entered. But i agree mine is repetitious and complicated

Comment: I'd definitely send your professor an email asking for clarification for anything you're not sure about. If you need help with the do/while section, create another question on here. With the answer I gave, I extrapolated only what changes into those if statements. Like I said, keep it simple. Only the things that change (name of month, and days in month) were given variables. Then after it fills in those variables, it fills out the string in only a single place, in case that would have to change down the line.

Answer (score 2):

[iFytil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28653840/4261176) is spot-on.
It's just a matter of [boolean algebra laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Monotone_laws). I recommend you read it and get the idea on the basics. 
That would help a lot future implementations of complex conditionals, especially those with multiple negations.

Furthermore, your code shows some overcomplexity. I'm not sure if there are any rules in your assignment, but it'd be way cleaner if you treated the things separately.
Instead of having two things evaluated at once (which month and leap year or not), leading to 12 x 2 conditionals, a good way to go is breaking it in two, leading to 12 + 2 conditionals (with a little if inside February). Also, when you have more than two comparisons, the switch-case structure is much more readable.

Let me explain:

```
String answer;
switch (MonthNumber) {
    case 1:
        answer = "The month is January. January has 31 days in it.";
        break;
    case 2:
        answer = "The month is February. ";
        if (Year % 4 == 0 && !(Year % 100 == 0 && Year % 400 != 0))
            // years divisible by 4, except those divisible by 100 and not by 400
            answer += "February has 29 days in it because this is a leap-year.";
        else
            answer += "February has 28 days in it because this is not a leap-year.";
        break;
    case 3:
        ... // you get the idea
}
```

Then, right after it, you parse for the leap-year text.

```
if (MonthNumber != 2) { // you have already completed the text in Feb
    if (Year % 4 == 0 && !(Year % 100 == 0 && Year % 400 != 0))
        answer += "and is also a leap-year.";
    else
        answer += "and it is not a leap-year.";
}
```

A small change in the output text would remove the need to check if it's February, but that's just a trick.

Answer (score 0):

can be simplified like this.

```
package leapmonth;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LeapMonth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String MonthInput;
    int YearInput;
    String[] MonthArray = {"January","February","March"
                            ,"April","May","June"
                            ,"July","August","September"
                            ,"October","November","December"
                          }; 
    // array always started from 0 then January should be 0

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " HELLO, WELCOME TO LEAPMONTH ");
    Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter the numerical respresentation of the month : ");
    MonthInput = Integer.parseInt(Input);
    Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter the year : ");
    YearInput = Integer.parseInt(Input);

    if( MonthInput != 2 && Year % 4 == 0 && (Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 == 0))
    {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The month is " + MonthArray[MonthInput+1] + ". " + MonthArray[MonthInput+1] + " has 31 days in it" + " and is also a leap year "); 
    }   
    else if( MonthInput != 2 && Year % 4 != 0 && (Year % 100 == 0 || Year % 400 != 0))
    {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The month is " + MonthArray[MonthInput+1] + ". " + MonthArray[MonthInput+1] + " has 31 days in it" + " and it is not a leap year ");   
    }
    else if( MonthInput == 2 && Year % 4 == 0 && (Year % 100 != 0 || Year % 400 ==0))
    {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The month is " + MonthArray[MonthInput+1] + ". " + MonthArray[MonthInput+1] + " has 29 days in it because this is a leap year ");  
    } 
    else if( MonthInput == 2 && Year % 4 != 0 && (Year % 100 == 0 || Year % 400 != 0))
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The month is " + MonthArray[MonthInput+1] + ". " + MonthArray[MonthInput+1] + " has 28 days in it because this is not a leap year ");
    }
   }
}
```